# Code to generate many test case files and its contents

Tags: python, shell

I have hunderds of files that needs to be grouped and modified. Instead, I thought it might be easier to somehow regenerate the files with correct data and formats.

There are 3 modes; mode1, mode2 and mode3. Each mode contains 45 test cases, which are named as:
(For Mode 1): mode1_test1.txt, mode1_test2.txt...
(For Mode 2): mode2_test1.txt, mode2_test2.txt ...

Let's look into mode1_test1.txt:

```
#Title: /mydrive/test/mode1_test1.txt
#Author: Me
#Description: We will test Mode1 using testcase 1

$init=bench

## Sourcing all common files:
source ../common_mode1.txt

##Initiate test
$init address 0x9876 data 0x1234 -type write
$init address 0x8765 data 0x2344 -type write

## Test Result
source ../expected_data/mode1_test1.txt

quit
```

mode1_test2.txt

```
#Title: /mydrive/test/mode1_test2.txt
#Author: Me
#Description: We will test Mode1 using testcase 2

$init=bench

## Sourcing all common files:
source ../common_mode1.txt

##Initiate test
$init address 0x9876 data 0x1234 -type write
$init address 0x8765 data 0x2344 -type write

## Test Result
source ../expected_data/mode1_test2.txt

quit
```

This is an example of the test case files and functionally incorrect, which I am not too worried about.

The code to generate these scripts needs to source the common files, initiate the testbench, read/write same data and finally source the expected data file for check.

As I have mentioned, there are 45 test cases for each mode. What is the easiest way to generate these files using shell/python?

One idea is to have shell script shown it this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883767/script-to-generate-other-scripts)

However, are there any other, relatively simple way to generate these files and its contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Are you looking to generate 45 files based on a string template that you use with some data source to generate the contents?  If so, check out jinja2

Comment: @JonSG, yes, that is the idea.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty example of building an individual output based on data and a template in jinja2.

```py
import jinja2

data = ["1", "2"]

template_text = """
#Title: /mydrive/test/mode1_test{{ item }}.txt
#Description: We will test Mode1 using testcase {{ item }}
"""

template = jinja2.Environment().from_string(template_text)

for item in data:
    print(template.render({"item": item}))
```

This could be extended to read the template from a file and to write the results to many individual files rather than printing.